# Incorrect date format in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, date-formatting, sqldatatypes

I have been trying to convert varchar string in one of my column to `DATETIME` (to insert into another column of type `DATETIME`).

However I keep running into the following error: -

```
Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '16MAY2017:09:30:00' for function str_to_date
```

My query to insert from one column into another looks like this: -

```
Update Data f1 set f1.Local_ETD_DT = str_to_date(f1.LOCAL_ETD, '%d/%M/%Y:%H:%i:%s');
```

Comment: Please share the `CREATE TABLE data` statement with some example data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data doesn't have slashes (`/`) between the day, month and year values. Remove them and you should be OK:

```
Update Data f1 set f1.Local_ETD_DT = str_to_date(f1.LOCAL_ETD, '%d%M%Y:%H:%i:%s');
-- "/" Removed here ----------------------------------------------^-^
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland `%b` seems more correct, indeed, although empirically `%M` works just fine

Comment: @Caadi0 Can be possible you should use `%d%b%Y:%H:%i:%s` as format... %b Abbreviated month name (Jan..Dec) instead of %M Month name (January..December). Month May is the same in %b in %M formats.. it's not clear from your question what format you should use, it depends off your data.